# Android 6.0 Marshmallow Update Deletes All Of My Photos & Videos

Tags: updates, photos, video, 6.0-marshmallow, android-one

My Infinix Hot2 X510 (Running on AndroidOne) got Android 6.0 Marshmallow on Friday, this is the good news :).
The bad news is after updating the system all of my photos & videos are GONE, disappeared without a trace :(

I tried to search using installed apps like google photo, file manager and previously installed apps (before update) like ES Explorer by all ways no photos.

Keep in mind that all previous updates was done smoothly without any problems and even that update never warn me about deleting any thing and other files on phone remain as is.

Did I miss anything, should I look in somewhere or in someway, or is there some app can help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, all your apps are there, but just the media is gone?  What about app settings?

Comment: @MartyFried Just the media & other files was deleted not settings, even SMS & contacts are kept although some problems was in contacts like the name wasn't shown on dialing but the number only. The contacts needed to be deleted and restored to work properly.

Comment: The AndroidOne upgrade to  6.0  (Marshmallow) is a mess. If someone got this update do yourself a favor  don't update and wait for the next update 6.0.1 (or whatever). There are some other problems appeared beside the file deletion problem. last note my bad update size was 8xx MB and I heard that there was another update sized 6xx MB didn't  cause any problem (just heard not sure).

Comment: Well, my phone came with Marshmellow, so I have no direct experience, although I'm active on several Android forums and never read about this happening.  Usually, unless you do a factory reset, nothing will delete your media, not even installing a different ROM.  Apps and settings yes, but not the internal memory partition.  Perhaps your particular update either did a factory reset, or had that option, and then the apps were automatically restored by Google, which is normal (apps, but not settings, I think).

Comment: There are many complains about the problems mentioned above in many Infinix Facebook group posts (in Arabic).

Comment: Well, sorry I can't help.  To be honest, I never heard of Infinix. :-(

Comment: For the future, you can keep backups of all your photos, videos, and other valuable files -- in the cloud, or elsewhere. For now, it must be very frustrating, what happened to you, and I don't know what to advise you. Could you phone Infinix for help?